# Application server log are exact replica, when there are more than 1 pods in Kubernetes Horizontal Pod Autoscaler

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, jboss5.x, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I have Horizontal Pod Autoscaler with max 4 pods and when there are more than 1 pods running, i see application server log in all the pods are exact replica.

**Example:**

My Application server is Jboss 5.1

When there are 3 pods reunning like Pod 1, Pod 2, Pod 3

If i access jboss server log file through the terminal in each of these pod's, content of server.log file is exact replica in all 3 pods

**Is this how the server logs will be, when it comes to Horizontal Pod Autoscaler ?**

Deployment config:

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "32"
  creationTimestamp: "2022-04-06T07:02:40Z"
  generation: 149
  labels:
    customerid: 4000-sss-prod
    environment: prod
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:spec:
        f:replicas: {}
    manager: vpa-recommender
    operation: Update
    subresource: scale
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:spec:
        f:progressDeadlineSeconds: {}
        f:revisionHistoryLimit: {}
        f:selector: {}
        f:strategy:
          f:rollingUpdate:
            .: {}
            f:maxSurge: {}
            f:maxUnavailable: {}
          f:type: {}
        f:template:
          f:metadata:
            f:labels:
              .: {}
              f:app: {}
              f:version: {}
          f:spec:
            f:containers:
              k:{"name":"ecommerce"}:
                .: {}
                f:env:
                  .: {}
                  k:{"name":"JAVA_OPTS"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                  k:{"name":"JIRA_KEY"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:value: {}
                  k:{"name":"SF_ACCOUNT_NUMBER"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:value: {}
                f:imagePullPolicy: {}
                f:name: {}
                f:ports:
                  .: {}
                  k:{"containerPort":9443,"protocol":"TCP"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:containerPort: {}
                    f:protocol: {}
                f:resources:
                  .: {}
                  f:limits: {}
                  f:requests: {}
                f:securityContext:
                  .: {}
                  f:capabilities:
                    .: {}
                    f:add: {}
                  f:privileged: {}
                f:terminationMessagePath: {}
                f:terminationMessagePolicy: {}
                f:volumeMounts:
                  .: {}
                  k:{"mountPath":"/var/persistent/"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:mountPath: {}
                    f:name: {}
            f:dnsPolicy: {}
            f:restartPolicy: {}
            f:schedulerName: {}
            f:securityContext: {}
            f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {}
            f:volumes:
              .: {}
              k:{"name":"XXXX3-persistent-pv"}:
                .: {}
                f:name: {}
                f:persistentVolumeClaim: {}
    manager: Go-http-client
    operation: Update
    time: "2022-04-06T07:02:40Z"
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations: {}
      f:status:
        f:conditions:
          .: {}
          k:{"type":"Available"}:
            .: {}
            f:type: {}
          k:{"type":"Progressing"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
    manager: kube-controller-manager
    operation: Update
    time: "2022-06-25T06:11:17Z"
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:customerid: {}
          f:environment: {}
      f:spec:
        f:template:
          f:metadata:
            f:labels:
              f:customerid: {}
              f:environment: {}
          f:spec:
            f:containers:
              k:{"name":"ecommerce"}:
                f:env:
                  k:{"name":"JAVA_OPTS"}:
                    f:value: {}
                f:image: {}
                f:resources:
                  f:limits:
                    f:cpu: {}
                    f:memory: {}
                  f:requests:
                    f:cpu: {}
                    f:memory: {}
            f:nodeSelector: {}
            f:volumes:
              k:{"name":"XXXX3-persistent-pv"}:
                f:persistentVolumeClaim:
                  f:claimName: {}
    manager: GoogleCloudConsole
    operation: Update
    time: "2023-04-03T07:00:21Z"
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          f:deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: {}
      f:status:
        f:availableReplicas: {}
        f:conditions:
          k:{"type":"Available"}:
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:lastUpdateTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
            f:status: {}
          k:{"type":"Progressing"}:
            f:lastUpdateTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
        f:observedGeneration: {}
        f:readyReplicas: {}
        f:replicas: {}
        f:updatedReplicas: {}
    manager: kube-controller-manager
    operation: Update
    subresource: status
    time: "2023-04-13T11:58:40Z"
  name: ecommerce
  namespace: 4000-sss-prod
  resourceVersion: "7896582563"
  uid: fghyytu-k258-4jb4-77z0-XXXXXXXXXXXX
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 3
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ecommerce
      version: beta
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: ecommerce
        customerid: 4000-sss-prod
        environment: prod
        version: beta
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: SF_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
          value: "4000"
        - name: JIRA_KEY
          value: sss-prod
        - name: JAVA_OPTS
          value: -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/persistent/auto-heap-dumps
            -Dxxx4.host.address=www.gosss.com -Dxxx4.db.connection=jdbc:oracle:thin:@4000db.xxxx.net:1521:stage
            -Dxxx4.db.user=DRY_RUN_BOND -Dxxx4.db.access.token=dry_run_bond -Djboss.server.log.dir=/var/XXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXX/logs/
        image: gcr.io/XXXXXXXXXXXX-core/XXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXX_40
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: ecommerce
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9443
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "4"
            memory: 18Gi
          requests:
            cpu: "1"
            memory: 8Gi
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            add:
            - SYS_ADMIN
          privileged: true
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/persistent/
          name: XXXX3-persistent-pv
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      nodeSelector:
        cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: stable-prod-e2
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 150
      volumes:
      - name: XXXX3-persistent-pv
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: 4000-sss-fs
status:
  availableReplicas: 3
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-04-06T07:42:00Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2023-04-03T06:58:35Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "ecommerce-7cd6dd596c" has successfully progressed.
    reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  - lastTransitionTime: "2023-04-13T11:58:40Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2023-04-13T11:58:40Z"
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  observedGeneration: 149
  readyReplicas: 3
  replicas: 3
  updatedReplicas: 3
```

Comment: Can you share your deployment configuration?

Comment: Updated deployemnt yaml,

Comment: Where are located your logs files?

Comment: Djboss.server.log.dir=/var/XXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXX/logs/



actual path: /var/persist/ecommerce/logs/

Comment: /var/persist or /var/persistent? In the second case, it's normal to have the same logs because you write the data in the same disk space, you have no difference between the replicas.

Comment: apologies for the typo its - persistent

/var/persistent/ecommerce/logs/

Comment: So, you use the same space for the logs in all the replicas, there is no 1 log files per replica, therefore it's normal to see the exact same thing, because it's the same storage space!!